# Python - operate a method

Tags: python, class, methods

A question from a beginner:

1. Can someone explain to me please why the method `change_pos` isn't working and doesn't change the sitting position from True to False (and either the opposite way) in the following code?
2. How do I implement this `change_pos` method to whole instances `(p1, p2)` in one line of code?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, Personality, isSitting):
        self.name=name
        self.Personality = Personality
        self.isSitting=isSitting 

    def sit_down(self):
        self.isSitting=True

    def stand_up(self):
        self.isSitting=False

    def change_pos(self):
        if (self.isSitting==True):
            self.isSitting==False
        else: 
            self.isSitting==True

p1=Person("Alice", "aggressive", False)
p2=Person("Becky", "talkative", True)

print (p1.name,'is', p1.isSitting ,'about sitting')
print (p2.name,'is', p2.isSitting ,'about sitting')

p2.change_pos()

print (p1.name,'is', p1.isSitting ,'about sitting')
print (p2.name,'is', p2.isSitting ,'about sitting')
```

The output is:

```
Alice is False about sitting
Becky is True about sitting
Alice is False about sitting
Becky is True about sitting
```

Comment: You have 2 typos in `change_pos`. You have `self.isSitting==False` instead of `self.isSitting=False`

Comment: just `def change_pos(self): self.isSitting = not self.isSitting`

Comment: As for your 2nd question, just do `for p in (p1, p2): p.change_pos()`

Comment: Thanks, I fix that and now use self.isSitting=False

Comment: What do you mean 'The output is ~~'? Is that what you want?

Comment: BTW, don't do tests that compare something to True or False, like your `if (self.isSitting==True):`. Instead, write that test like this: `if self.isSitting:`

Comment: Thank you...  and what if I would have thousands of instances  (and not just p1,p2) ?     so, what can be written instead:   for p in (p1, p2): p.change_pos()